# odoo How to implement javascript/jquery on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-11

Hi i am using odoo 11 and ve added Button along Create and Import buttons. That button is Export button see figure for understanding:

[image]

Basically i am overriding and those Create and Import are in build. I placed them here bcz my custom button was replacing them so i also placed Create and Import along.
But with respect to **Export** button and Jquery i ve problem that button does nt responds with jquery.

My Modules and files
**web_export_view\web_export_view\static\src\xml\web_export_view_template.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">


<t t-name="ListView.buttons">
    <div class="o_list_buttons">
        <t t-if="widget.is_action_enabled('create')">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_list_button_add" accesskey="c">
                Create
            </button>
        </t>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_list_button_save" accesskey="s">
            Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm o_list_button_discard" accesskey="j">
            Discard
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-default export_treeview_xls" value="hh" type="button" title="Export xls">
            Export
        </button>
    </div>
</t>


</templates>
```

**web_export_view\web_export_view\static\src\js\web_export_view.js**

```
odoo.define('web_export_view', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var QWeb = core.qweb;

    var _t = core._t;

    ListView.include({
        redraw: function () {
            var self = this;


         events: {
         "click .export_treeview_xls": "your_function",
     },

     your_function: function () {
              alert('Button Clicked');
     },

    });
});
```

**web_export_view\web_export_view\views\web_export_view_view.xml**

```
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="web_export_view assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_export_view/static/src/js/web_export_view.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

**web_export_view\manifest**

```
{
    'name': 'Web Export Current View',
    'version': '10.0.1.0.0',
    'category': 'Web',
    'author': 'Me',

    'depends': [
        'web',
    ],
    "data": [
        'views/web_export_view_view.xml',
    ],
    'qweb': [
        "static/src/xml/web_export_view_template.xml",
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

Comment: anyine??????????

Comment: its not even giving alert()

Comment: Does it throw any javascript error?

Comment: no it does nt throw any error

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closed bracket in your javascript code.

That piece of code should be like this

```
odoo.define('web_export_view', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView');
    var QWeb = core.qweb;

    var _t = core._t;

    ListView.include({
        redraw: function () {
            var self = this;
        }, // <<<<< You missed this


        events: {
            "click .export_treeview_xls": "your_function",
        },

        your_function: function () {
            alert('Button Clicked');
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: i still cant get any respond from button

Comment: @user3162878 Have you reinstalled the module?

Comment: @user3162878 Yes, it has to be RE-installed. I mean installing it again. In Odoo, they say Upgrade.